# Deserialize altered object

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, audit

I have a requirement to store a **Serialized** [using *Binary Serialization*] Object during *Create/Update/Delete* in database for **Audit** Purposes.
Another requirement is to be able to view the differences between 2 audit log entries at any point of time, i.e. to be able to **Deserialize** 2 objects of the *same* type and compare their property values.

Now all this is cool until you release a new version in which this audited object has changed - say you have removed a couple of properties and added a new one: now try to **Deserialize** into it from an old audit log entry and it would **fail**.

Our webserver admins are *very strict* and would not let us install anything in GAC, so the question is how to resolve this problem assuming you only have latest Assemly version installed?

Comment: Any reason why you don't want to use XmlSerialization ? BinarySerialization for auditing is pure hell

Comment: i think yes. it depends on your usecase but what are you going to do with the audit-data ? show it to some technician ? no need to have an object to deserialize it. need to print it well on a webpage ? use xslt. show changes made to an object ? use a generic approach to diff your xml-documents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For new fields, you have the [`OptionalFieldAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.optionalfieldattribute.aspx)

Next to that, I think you'll enjoy this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229752%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) on MSDN.

Comment: I'll accept, although this isn't an ideal solution for a new project in its very beginning.